# unable to understand this Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript. can anyone tell me what kind of declaration or object creation it is ?
where i can learn this kind of basic information.

```
var portfolio = portfolio || {},
        $portfolioItems = $('#portfolio-items'),
        $filtrable = $('#portfolio-filter');
```

Comment: [Values, variables and literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals),
[Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation),
[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: You could start with the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line:

```
var portfolio = portfolio || {}
```

is setting a variable `portfolio` as itself if it is not a value that evaluates to false (like 0, null, undefined, NaN, etc.), otherwise as a new empty object.

The next 2 lines are using jQuery to set 2 other variables named `$portfolioItems` and `$filterable` to jQuery objects created by searching the DOM for elements with the IDs "portfolio-items" and "portfolio-filter".

Comment: "if it is not false or null" -- or empty string, or zero, undefined...

Comment: Which all just evaluate to false in this context

Comment: @mclaassen—the way you have written it infers that they are the only two values that will convert to false.

Comment: thanks a lot. but still didnt understand why the object is initialized by its own name. where is the beginning!!

Comment: @Ahmed It might be the case that portfolio had already been created and given a value, in that case we want to use the existing value of portfolio. Otherwise it would be 'undefined' in which case we want it to just be an empty object instead of being 'undefined'.